# html handler not working || using javascript as well

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

My goal is to create a small point & click game to run in the browser.

Made two of the operators work before, but now they suddenly stopped working.

Fixed the issue with the missing }. mouseRelease still doesn't seem to work, even if the other functions are not being called.

```js
function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function mouseOut() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function mouseRelease() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<object id="demo" type="image/svg+xml" data="box.svg" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()" onmousemove="mouseMove()" onmouseup="mouseRelease()">
</object>`enter code here`
```

Comment: I made a snippet and formatted it. You have a missing `}` on the mouseout function and it gives console errors

Comment: Voting to close as Typo-type:  _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: You're missing the mouseMove() function

Comment: Hidden elements are not responsing any pointer actions.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help.
I fixed the issue with the missing }.
Though it's still not working, even I delete the mouseover and mouseout functions..